# Toggle link to make the clickable/unclickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I've successfully made the links clickable but how do i make them revert back to their unclickable state again?

HTML

```
<div id="links">
    http://google.com <br>
    http://facebook.com <br>
    http://youtube.com
</div>
<button>Toggle!</button>
```

JavaScript

```
$.fn.replaceUrl = function() {  
    var regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(
            $(this).html().replace(regexp,'<a href="$1">$1</a>')
        );
    });
    return $(this);
}

$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').replaceUrl();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6Zvs6/

Comment: A fiddle is a great thing to add to a question, but please also post the code in to the question too. That way people can help you should jsFiddle be offline, and this question will also be useful in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2ttWS/

Code:

```
$.fn.replaceUrl = function() {
    if($(this).find('a').length > 0) {
        $(this).find('a').each(function() {
           $(this).replaceWith($(this).text());
        });
    }
    else {
        var regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;
        this.each(function() {
            $(this).html(
            $(this).html().replace(regexp, '<a href="$1">$1</a>'));
        });
    }
    return $(this);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
$.fn.removeHyperlink = function() {  
    var regexp = /<\/?a.*?>/gi;
    this.each(function() {
        $(this).html(
            $(this).html().replace(regexp,'')
        );
    });
    linksShown = false;
    return $(this);
}
```

Here is [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/MPA25/1/).
This is not advanced so it can break some complicated links, but should work with all normal cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.fn.replaceUrl = function() {  
    var regexp = /((ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?)/gi;
    this.each(function()
    {
        if(($(this).html()).indexOf("href")!= -1)
        {
                var tx = ($(this).html()).split("</a>");
                var tmp="";
                for(var i=0;i<tx.length-1;i++)
                {
                  if((tx[i].indexOf("href")!=-1)&&(tx[i].indexOf("<br>")==-1))
                      tmp+=tx[i].split(">")[1]+" <br>";
            else
                tmp+=tx[i].split(">")[2]+" <br>";
                }

           $(this).html(tmp)
        }
        else
        {
        $(this).html(
                       $(this).html().replace(regexp,'<a href="$1">$1</a>')

        );
        }
    });
    return $(this);
}

$('button').click(function(){
    $('div').replaceUrl();
});
```